# Кол-во строк с одинаковым значением поля

Tags: mysql

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT
    salesorderid,
    integration_betapost.goods_to_products.shipping_order_row_good_id,
    vtiger_inventoryproductrel.quantity
FROM
    vtiger_salesorder
INNER JOIN vtiger_inventoryproductrel ON vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_inventoryproductrel.id
INNER JOIN vtiger_products ON vtiger_inventoryproductrel.productid = vtiger_products.productid
INNER JOIN integration_betapost.goods_to_products ON vtiger_products.productid = integration_betapost.goods_to_products.productid
WHERE
    sostatus = 'Отправлять'
```

Который выводит результат вида [result](http://joxi.ru/823KeVztNQaL2O)
Вопрос, как посчитать сумму строк с одинаковым `salesorderid` и сумму строк с одинаковыми `salesorderid` и  `shipping_order_row_good_id`?

Comment: Обернуть группирующим запросом да посчитать... проблема-то в чём? Если хочется всё в одном запросе - добавить `WITH ROLLUP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    salesorderid,
    integration_betapost.goods_to_products.shipping_order_row_good_id,
    sum(Quantity)
FROM
    vtiger_salesorder
INNER JOIN vtiger_inventoryproductrel ON vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_inventoryproductrel.id
INNER JOIN vtiger_products ON vtiger_inventoryproductrel.productid = vtiger_products.productid
INNER JOIN integration_betapost.goods_to_products ON vtiger_products.productid = integration_betapost.goods_to_products.productid
WHERE
    sostatus = 'Отправлять'
GROUP BY
    salesorderid
    ,integration_betapost.goods_to_products.shipping_order_row_good_id
order by salesorderid desc
```